# Write MDX / DAX on azure analysis services and copy data to azure data warehous using ADF

Tags: ssas, azure-data-factory

How can we create ADF pipeline to write MDX/DAX query from azure data factory to Azure Analysis Service Tabular Models and get the data stored into tables in Azure Data Warehous Tables?

Comment: Hey@Shruti, did it answer your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct SSAS or AAS connector available in ADF .
So there is a workaround:

1. Create a linked server on an IaaS/On prem/SQL MI server connecting to the tabular model
2. via openrowset execute the query in SQL server to tabular model
3. In ADF SQL would act as linked service

My blog for Reference:
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/16/copy-data-from-ssas-aas-through-azure-data-factory/

Comment: Yes, it helped Nandan.

Comment: Great to hear! Can you please upvote and mark it as answer as it would benefit other community members as well